# Why I must cast to Generic Type T even if I know it returns correctly?

Tags: java, generics

My code:

```
private static <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        if (clazz.equals(String.class)) {
            return (T) new String("abc");//line x
        } else {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        }

    }
```

As you see, in `line x`, `T` have to be `String.class` and returns `String`. But compile failed without casting the result to `T`.

Change `line x` to `return new String("abc");` results `Incompatible types`.

Comment: This is really not what templates are meant for. Of course, it is apparent to you that it will always return something of type T - but is that apparent to the compiler? If T isn't String, there's still some pathway (accessible or not) that returns the wrong type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not take into account the `if` statement.

So all it sees is that you need to return a `T` (of which it has no further knowledge). It did not infer that `T` must be `String` here.

You can avoid the warning that you get for the "unchecked cast to erased type" by doing

```
return clazz.cast("abc");
```

Comment: This does not produce the same result. OP's code creates a new instance of a String every time, but your code returns the same (interned) String every time. Maybe `clazz.cast(new String("abc"));` it should also be noted that calling cast() still involves an unsafe cast, but it's buried inside the cast method.

Comment: @Bohemian: I silently autocorrected that `new String()` part. In most cases, you don't want a new String instance. The `cast` is not unsafe here, because the `if` statement already checked for type compatibility (which was the point of this question, I think some other languages have stronger type inference that takes this kind of conditionals into account).

Comment: sorry - by "unsafe" I didn't mean unsafe from a practical view, but rather that the compiler considers it unsafe and generated a warning. Specifically, the `cast()` method does `return (T) obj;` and is annotated with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` - Calling `cast()` just pushes the warning out of *your* code into the JDK's (which I am cool with - I use this pattern reasonably often myself).

Comment: What I intended to say (and what OP was apparently expecting) is that it could be thought of as a shortcoming in the compiler that it considers the cast in the original code unsafe and generates a warning. Inside of a conditional block such as in the code in the question, the cast can never fail. Some systems do support that kind of inference. Witness for example Eclipse, which will autocomplete methods on narrowed types inside of `if (x instanceof Something){` (and also automatically insert the necessary cast that the compiler requires).

Comment: And yes, the workaround is to provide these the pre-packaged warning-suppressing utility methods such as `Class.cast()` or `Collections.emptyList()` in the standard library.

Comment: @Bohemian: But it's not unchecked. Because `cast()` checks it. It's true that it gets rid of an unchecked cast.

Comment: @newacct like Thilo's answer, `cast()` has an "unchecked" cast from a *compiler* perspective (even though it is *logically* checked).

Comment: @Bohemian: You are making it sound like somehow by using `cast()`, you can "hide" an unchecked cast so that you don't see a warning anymore, but it's equally unsafe. But that's simply not true. A Java Standard Library API will never allow you to do something unsafe without a warning (where unsafe includes stuff like heap pollution). What `cast()`'s internal code is doesn't matter -- what matters is its API -- its API does not allow you to cause heap pollution by using it, whereas an unchecked cast is unsafe because it can cause heap pollution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you can't cast String for every class. Think about that the T is a Number class, that will you throws a ClassCastException.

You can try this to solve the problem:

```
return (T) ((Object) new String("abc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the cast as follows:

```
if (clazz.equals(String.class)) {
    return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance("abc");
}
return clazz.newInstance();
```

You'll have to catch (and ignore) a few exceptions.